# When is device unique id the same on windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm building an application that is using push notifications, but I want the possibility to send "test" message's to certain phones. I don't know which phones it will be at launch. The way I would like to solve this is by using the "DeviceUniqueId" and using a second app to retrieve it with an name. But I also read questions that it can change, for example when the app is published by a different publisher.

So my question is:

When is the DeviceUniqueId the same and when is it different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WP 7.1 apps running on WP 8 devices the value of `DeviceExtendedProperties("DeviceUniqueId")` will be unique across all applications and will not change if the phone is updated with a new version of the operating system.

For WP 8.0 apps running on WP 8 devices the value of `DeviceExtendedProperties("DeviceUniqueId")` will be unique per device and per app publisher.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)